# Getting error UPGRADE_HOST_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ID while upgrade bin for Audio Device Qualcomm

Tags: qualcomm, audio-device

I am trying to upgrade firmware on audio device. My audio device chip is QCC512X_QCC302X.SRC.1.0 and I am using ADK_QCC512X_ROM_V21_WIN_6.4.2.25.
As per App its compatible with above chip.
"The command 'Upgrade Binary' is only applicable to CSRA681xx, QCC302x/3x and QCC512x devices ('Usage Page' should be 0xFF00)."
But when I try to connect with device for upgrade bin opertaion, I get below error.

Starting the 'Upgrade Binary' operation...
ERROR: Received Error Indication from chip, error code: 0x11(UPGRADE_HOST_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ID)

Any solution, workaround or hint about above problem.

Thanks

I tried to use hiddfucmd.exe available with ADK to upgrade bin. As per my expectation, this application should have upgraded new firmeware and give me new version after upgrading.